# after deploying spring boot application on wildfly how to call an ejb from local bean

Tags: ejb, wildfly

how to call EJB from wildfly

I have deployed the spring boot application on wildfly and now how should i call entity local bean from wildfly so it can call it as ejb what is the process to run crud application after deploying on wildfly